# Fog/Carrierwave config for Rails app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, carrierwave, fog

I'm trying to set up Carrierwave and Fog to handle image and file uploads on a rails app that I have hosted on AWS' Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm a little confused on how to properly set up the Fog config.

I tried using my AWS Access and Secret keys (commented out in the example below).  That through an error on my EB CLI (ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.)

I'm tyring to use IAM instead of having my Access/Secret codes in my ruby code.  Can anyone tell me how to set this up properly?

Here's my config file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|


  # Use local storage if in development or test
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :file
    end
  end

  # Use AWS storage if in production
  if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :fog
    end
  end


  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                             # required
    # :aws_access_key_id      => 'My Access',            # required
    # :aws_secret_access_key  => 'My Secret',     # required
    :use_iam_profile => true,
    :region                 => 'eu-west-2'                        # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXXXXXXXXX'               # required
  #config.fog_host       = 'https://assets.example.com'           # optional, defaults to nil
  config.fog_public     = false                                  # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a setup that works for me:

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['aws_access_key_id'],       # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['aws_secret_access_key'],   # required
    #region:                'Singapore',                 # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    #host:                  's3.example.com',            # optional, defaults to nil
    #endpoint:              'olucube-images.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['fog_directory']             # required
  #config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
#  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" }, # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

and I used figaro gem to hold my credentials as follow:

config/application.yml

```
aws_access_key_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
aws_secret_access_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
fog_directory: 'myAppName'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit a of a wild ride.  I had a hard time figuring out that Figaro gem.  It's probably simple but I didn't really understand it.  So for a test, I put my keys directly in the code.  It still didn't work.

I pushed my code to github (publicly) and didn't think too much of it.  I was going to change the keys just in case.  Before I was able to do that someone found my code on github and gained access to my AWS account.  They started a bunch of EC2 instances and racked up $3000 worth of usage in a few hours!

My AWS account got suspended and I'm still dealing with having the charges reversed.

Anyway.  I found out that you can actually set environment variables on the Elastic Beanstalk web interface.  Its under Configuration → Software Configuration.  So I did that instead of using Fiagro (much safer IMO).  Now it works great.  I simplified my Carrierwave config file to only use AWS calling the environment variables from EB.  Here's the file:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|

config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
config.fog_credentials = {
  provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],
  region: ENV['S3_REGION']
}
config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
config.fog_public = false
config.storage = :fog
```

end

I changed my uploader files to use fog too.  Here's an example:

```
# app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Everything works great now.  I hope this helps someone else.